# How to unregister zoom behavior of SVG element in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have register the zoom behavior with  element, now I want to toggle between zoom-able and not zoom-able, does anyone know how to **unregister** the zoom behavior of SVG element ?

```
var svg = d3.select("#topology-div")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "topology-map")
    .attr("width", data.width)
    .attr("height", data.height)
    .call(zoom); // <<-- I want unregister zoom later
```

Answer (score 2):

do you mean like:

```
svgElement.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom"); //deactivate zoom behavior
```

Comment: This could be workable, as it create a new zoom(). But that still does NOT equal to the state of selection before do d3.select...call(zoom), it adds event "mousedown.zoom" and its listener to the selection. I am not sure if it has any side effect to register an empty zoom().

Comment: I got it, passing null to event type will remove the listeners, for this case, just do "svg.on('.zoom', null);" That should be the answer!